# Get current page id and page title inside the theme functions.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to get the current page id and page title inside the current themes functions.php?.

Note: I'm not referring post id.

I have tried following functions inside the themes->twentytwentytwo->functions.php file and did not work.

```php
prin_r(the_title());
print_r(get_queried_object_id());
print_r(get_the_title());
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand functions.php is included too early to use $post or get_queried_object_id().

What I've done before is create a function in functions.php that you can call in your template and pass it the id or the title.

For instance in your functions.php:

```
function myPage($pageId, $pageTitle) {
//Do whatever you want and return the result
}
```

Then in your template just call the function:

```
<?php 
$myPage(get_the_ID(), get_the_title());
?>
```

Hope it helps